# UINavigation PushtoViewcontroller replaced with addsubview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I was previously doing this

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:OBJ animated:YES];`

But now I replaced this with

`[self.view addSubview:OBJ.view];`

so the layout is changed for `iPhone4 and iPhone5` (I have only one `.xib` for this). It is working fine if I use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:OBJ animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

put this code on your `OBJ` Class

```
self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Comment: Its not working for me, I have some buttons and UIImageView in the bottom in the xib, and i have provide some Autoresizing from (left, right and bottom) within the xib.<br/>It is working fine for iPhone 5 and if I am push this **OBJ class** on navigationcontroller. @Kapil Maheshwari

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `autoresizingMask` for all subViews of your OBJ class's view. Then only it 'll work out. Try setting

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin,
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin,
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
```

based on how you need to present from bottom.n